# How do I get Java to output unique integers from a command-line argument?

Tags: java, arrays, unique

The code below checks to ensure the command-line arguments are integers? However, I need it to  only print each integer in the command line once, regardless of how many times that integer appears in the command line. How do I do that?

```
public class Unique {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) {
            try {
                int j = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                System.out.println(j);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Your command line argument "+ args[i] +" is a non-integer!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add all integers to a hashset and print the set.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, I'm not allowed to use any classes that serve as data structures such as ArrayList, etc.

Comment: sort your `args` array (`Arrays.Sort()`), loop over it and print the value only if the previous value is different from the current one.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, Arrays.Sort is part of Array.List. I'm not allowed to use those.

Comment: No it's not, it's part of the class `Arrays` which is neither an array, nor an arraylist, nor any other datastructure. It provides you with utility methods on datastructures but it's not one by itself. All you do is manipulate the starting datastructure you already have (`args[]`).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, thanks, but I can't visualize the solution. I've only been writing Java code for less than 48 hours. Please can you send in a sample of what you mean?

Comment: Please refer to my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class UniqueNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    args = new String[6];
    args[0] = "5";
    args[1] = "6";
    args[2] = "2";
    args[3] = "5";
    args[4] = "1";
    args[5] = "1";

    Arrays.sort(args); 
   // Sort the array. This will use natural order:
   // low -> high for integers, a -> z and low to high for strings
   // Essentially this causes our array to sort from low to high, despite not being integers

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { // Loop over the entire array
        if (i == 0) { // (1)
            System.out.println(args[0]);
        } else if (!(args[i - 1].equals(args[i]))) { // (2)
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
5
6
```

Clarification:

To make it easy to demonstrate, I've manually placed the values into the array. This makes no difference, you can just keep using your input method.

(1): Read `(2)` first. Because of the method below, we would essentially skip the first element. The second part of the `else if` essentially means `if i > 0`. If we wouldn't do this, we would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when we do `args[i - 1]` because that would try to access `args[-1]`. That's why we skip the first element: to avoid this. However, this would also mean that our first value (`1`) would be ignored. That's why we just want to make sure the first value is always printed.

(2): Now we check if the current element (`args[i]`) is equal (`.equals()`) to the previous elements (`args[i -1]`). If this is not the case (`!` inverts a statement), we print the current value.

With this method, you can solve your assignment without any datastructures apart from the the standard one.

More visualization:

Start:

```
5 6 2 5 1 1
```

Sort:

```
1 1 2 5 5 6
```

Loop:

```
!  
1 1 2 5 5 6 -> Output: 1

  !
1 1 2 5 5 6 -> Not different from previous one, no output

    !
1 1 2 5 5 6 -> Different from previous one, output: 1 2

      !
1 1 2 5 5 6 -> Different from previous one, output 1 2 5

        !
1 1 2 5 5 6 -> Not different from previous one, no output

          !
1 1 2 5 5 6 -> Different from previous one, output 1 2 5 6
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks! What if I had to do this without sorting? :)

Comment: @stburnish: Create a function that loops trough your array, gets the min value, stores it in a temp variable and prints it out. Then remove it from the array and do the same again. If the new minimum is the same as the temp variable, don't print it. Do this untill your array is empty. I'm not going to write this out though; the above solution entirely fits your requirements. You cannot solve this without using at least the `args` array.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Set. A set does not contain duplicates, as it is defined mathematically. Java has a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) class that does that job.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        int j = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        set.add(j);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Your command line argument "+ args[i] +" is a non-integer!");
    }
}
System.out.println(set);
```

Or iterate over all the elements like this:

```
for (Integer i : set)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner. This is hard for me to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Unique {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Set<Integer> uniqueIntegers = new HashSet<>();        

    for (int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) {
        try {
            int j = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            uniqueIntegers.add(j);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Your command line argument "+ args[i] +" is a non-integer!");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(uniqueIntegers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to Java. Doesn't the code above involve classes that can serve as data structures? Those are not allowed in this case.